# Why can't a boxed struct be borrowed as a trait?

Tags: rust, traits

Given a struct `S` implementing a trait `T`, why doesn't `Box<S>` implement `Borrow<dyn T>`?

The following code, that I would have expected to compile, doesn't:

```rust
trait T{}
struct S{}
impl T for S{}

fn f1(s: &S) -> &dyn T {
    s
}

fn f2(s: &Box<S>) -> &dyn T {
    std::borrow::Borrow::borrow(s)
}
```

Why does `f1` compile while `f2` doesn't? (The conversion from `&S` to `&dyn T` is done in the first case and not in the second).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to do with the way that type inference and type coercion work. The `Borrow<B>` trait's parameter is the type of the borrowed value, and the type checker needs to know what it is.

If you just write:

```
std::borrow::Borrow::borrow(s)
```

Then the type `B` in `Borrow<B>` will be inferred from the surrounding code. In your case it is inferred to be `dyn T` because that's the return value. However, `dyn T` is a completely different type from `S`, so it doesn't type-check.

Once the type checker knows that the value being returned is of type `&S` then it can coerce it to a `&dyn T`, but you need to give it that information:

```
fn f2(s: &Box<S>) -> &dyn T {
    let s: &S = std::borrow::Borrow::borrow(s);
    s
}
```

Or, more concisely:

```
fn f2(s: &Box<S>) -> &dyn T {
    std::borrow::Borrow::<S>::borrow(s)
}
```

---

The reason why [Sébastien Renauld's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57909436/493729) works is because `Deref` uses an associated type instead of a type parameter. The type-checker can easily infer the `<S as Deref>::Target` because there can only be one implementation of `Deref` per type and the associated `Target` type is uniquely determined. `Borrow` is different because `Box<S>` *could* implement `Borrow<()>`, `Borrow<i32>`, `Borrow<Box<Option<Vec<bool>>>>`,... so you have to be more explicit about which implementation you intend.

Answer (score 1):

`&Box<S>` is not directly equal to `Box<&S>`, and this is why it does not compile directly.

You can relatively easily fix this by [dereferencing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-Deref), like so:

```
use std::ops::Deref;
trait T{}
struct S{}
impl T for S{}

fn f1(s : &S) -> &(dyn T) {
    s
}

fn f2(s : &Box<S>) -> &(dyn T) {
    s.deref()
}
```

(The trait `Deref` is there for slightly easier readability)

The call to `deref()` operates over `&self`, so having `&Box<S>` is sufficient to call it. It simply returns `&S`, and since that implements `T` the types check out.

Comment: &Box<S> is not directly equal to Box<&S>. But isn't the type of &Box<S>::borow() actually &S in both cases ?